# Different outputs per number of partition in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I run spark code in my local machine and cluster.

I create SparkContext object for local machine with following code:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Trial")
```

I create SparkContext object for cluster with following code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(args(0)+" "+args(1)).getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
```

and I set the number of partition as 4 for local machine and cluster with following code

```
val dataset = sc.textFile("Dataset.txt", 4)
```

In my cluster, I created 5 workers. One of them is driver node, rest of them run as worker.

I expects that the results should be same. However, the results of two parts which are local and cluster are different. What are the reasons of the problem?

Comment: What do you mean with "results  .. are different"?

Comment: I make some mathematical calculation using dataset. The result is found using these calculations

Comment: Where is your `Dataset.txt` stored?

Comment: what are your "results" ?

Answer (score 0):

> I create SparkContext object for local machine with following code

and

> I create SparkContext object for cluster with following code:

It *appears* that you may have defined two different environments for `sc` and `spark` as you define `local[*]` explicitly for `sc` while taking some default value for `spark` (that may read external configuration files or take so-called master URL from `spark-submit`).

These *may* be different that *may* affect what you use.

> I expects that the results should be same. However, the results of two parts which are local and cluster are different. What are the reasons of the problem?

`Dataset.txt` you process in local vs cluster environments are different and hence the difference in the results. I'd strongly recommend using HDFS or some other shared file system to avoid such "surprises" in the future.

Comment: I am using same file and in my cluster I upload the files into hdfs. No matter how many partitions is set for spark in my computer, the result is always the same. On the other hand, if i set the number of partition 4, 8 or 16. The output is same as with local machine but if i set the number of parititon as 2, unfortunately the output of my program is changed.

Comment: I _hardly_ believe in what you say. Sorry. How can partitioning change results?! Can you include the different outputs per partition number to your question? How do you set the number of partitions?

Comment: `val dataset = sc.textFile("Dataset.txt", numberOfPart).persist()` . In this part, numberOfPart is specified the number of partition which will be used. I created the jar file of my project and then run it on my cluster.

Comment: Ouch! You `persist`! That means that you cache the `Dataset.txt` that may impact the following actions (esp. if you refresh the content of `Dataset.txt` outside Spark). How do you change the number of partitions per local vs cluster deployments?

Comment: I delete the persist but nothing change.

Comment: How are you executing the different tests? Can you post the entire code and how do you execute it per local vs cluster env and different number of partitions?

Comment: I send number of partition as argument to the main function and I run my code with spark-submit